# Preg grep array in pattern

Tags: preg-grep

I have a problem with pattern in preg_grep. I want to pull line with specific number, source files looks like this :

....

4221    Výstavba inženýrských sítí pro kapaliny a plyny

42211   Výstavba inženýrských sítí pro kapaliny

42212   Výstavba inženýrských sítí pro plyny

4222    Výstavba inženýrských sítí pro elektřinu a telekomunikace

42220   Výstavba inženýrských sítí pro elektřinu a telekomunikace

....

```
preg_grep($pattern, explode("\n", $nazevCzNace))
$pattern = '/^('.$number.')/';
$number = "4221"
```

When i am using code like above there is no problem, but i have to pull that number from array and there is a problem. my array is like:

```
$array[0][0]
```

When i echo $array[0][0] number is same like echo $number="4221". But when i put $array[0][0] into pattern i am getting this warning:

> Warning: preg_grep() [function.preg-grep]: Unknown modifier ':' in

Thanks for any help. I tried preg_quote (maybe wrong usage), and even $number = (string) $array[0][0] but that did not help too.

Comment: It should work, show us the code you have tried.

Comment: <?php
include ("head.php");

$getInfo = file_get_contents("http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_bas.cgi?ico=".$ico);

      
      preg_match_all('/<D:NACE zdroj="RES">(.*?)<\/D:NACE>/', $getInfo, $czNace);


$nazevCzNace = file_get_contents("./vendor/cznace.txt");

echo $czNace[0][0] ;


  $pattern = '/^('.$czNace[0][0].')/';


  print_r(preg_grep($pattern, explode("\n", $nazevCzNace))) ;

?>

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the problem. I was using $czNace[0] instead of $czNace[1]. $czNace[0] values arent just numbers but some strings containing (saw that strings after json_encode). I forgot i need to use values from array 1 for another preg_grep (double preg_grep)...